# J2ME: Set security permission programmatically

Tags: java-me, midp, ksoap

I have created a J2ME app and added it as jar in another app. The original app runs with maximum permission and works fine, but when I add it as jar in the 2nd app, I get security exception while making a web service call, and I noticed the app is running in minimum security.

I have added the midlet permissions for http and https in the JAD as well.

```
javax.microedition.io.Connector.http, javax.microedition.io.Connector.https
```

Any idea on how to fix this? The error I get is as below:

> ```
> java.lang.SecurityException: Application not authorized to access the restricted API
>   at com.sun.midp.security.SecurityToken.checkForPermission(+459)
>   at com.sun.midp.security.SecurityToken.checkForPermission(+15)
>   at com.sun.midp.midletsuite.MIDletSuiteImpl.checkForPermission(+20)
>   at com.sun.midp.dev.DevMIDletSuiteImpl.checkForPermission(+28)
>   at com.sun.midp.dev.DevMIDletSuiteImpl.checkForPermission(+7)
>   at com.sun.midp.io.ConnectionBaseAdapter.checkForPermission(+67)
>   at com.sun.midp.io.j2me.http.Protocol.checkForPermission(+17)
>   at com.sun.midp.io.ConnectionBaseAdapter.openPrim(+6)
>   at javax.microedition.io.Connector.openPrim(+299)
>   at javax.microedition.io.Connector.open(+15)
>   at org.ksoap2.transport.ServiceConnectionMidp.<init>(+11)
>   at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransport.getServiceConnection(+11)
>   at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransport.call(+51)
>   at com.vxceed.xnappexpresssync.comm.WebserviceCall.call(+28)
>   at com.vxceed.xnappexpresssync.comm.WebserviceCall.callServiceMethod(+112)
>   at com.vxceed.xnappexpresssync.utility.Generic.sendRequest(+22)
>   at com.vxceed.xnappexpresssync.main.Authentication.authenticateUser(+77)
>   at app.ui.ServerSync.sendServerRequest(+127)
>   at app.ui.LoginScreen.authenticateUser(+9)
>   at app.ui.LoginScreen.isLoginValidate(+76)
>   at app.ui.LoginScreen.keyPressed(+48)
>   at app.ui.MainAppScreen$Clean.run(+33)
>   at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(+237)
>   at java.util.TimerThread.run(+4)
> ```

Comment: no, but the 2nd app was created in netbeans, and strangely it works fine when i add the jar which was created in eclipse and run it in netbeans, where as eclipse puts up this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting the solution in case it helps someone.

The problem was with the emulator. When I used J2ME SDK 3.0, with the DefaultCldcPhone1 it worked fine.

Answer (score 2):

As Jonathan Knudsen states in ["Understanding MIDP 2.0's Security Architecture"](http://developers.sun.com/mobility/midp/articles/permissions/):

> The MIDP 2.0 specification defines an open-ended system of
>   permissions. To make any type of network connection, a MIDlet must
>   have an appropriate permission. For example, a MIDlet that uses HTTP
>   to talk to a server must have permission to open an HTTP connection.
>   The permissions defined in MIDP 2.0 correspond to network protocols,
>   but the architecture allows optional APIs to define their own
>   permissions.
>
> Each permission has a unique name; the MIDP 2.0 permissions are:
>
> - javax.microedition.io.Connector.http
> - javax.microedition.io.Connector.socket
> - javax.microedition.io.Connector.https
> - javax.microedition.io.Connector.ssl
> - javax.microedition.io.Connector.datagram
> - javax.microedition.io.Connector.serversocket
> - javax.microedition.io.Connector.datagramreceiver
> - javax.microedition.io.Connector.comm
> - javax.microedition.io.PushRegistry

If you are using above APIs then your .Jar file must be signed with Proper Sign Certificates.

Check the [article mentioned above](http://developers.sun.com/mobility/midp/articles/permissions/) for more detailed overview about Permissions.

You can buy such Certificate for example from [Verisign](http://www.verisign.com/).

Comment: Yes I have added all the permissions, but have not signed. Will try to get certificate, although I still wonder how it works on netbeans but when I re-created the same project in eclipse it fails.

Comment: well it may be possible that your netbeans has already those sign in certifications in it. ask to your Team Leader or Project Manager for it.

Comment: If you're going to copy the words of someone else, please provide proper attribution. I've done that here, but make sure you do this yourself in the future.